# Haskell increasing and decreasing value in list

Tags: haskell

I am trying to create a function

`update_money :: Transaction -> Int -> Int`

that takes a transaction and the current amount of money that you have, and returns the amount of money that you have
after the transaction. So if the transaction buys a stock the amount of money you have will decrease,
and if the transaction sells a stock the amount of money you have will increase. For example:

```
ghci> update_money ('B', 1, 10, "VTI", 5) 100
90
```

```
ghci> update_money ('S', 2, 10, "VTI", 5) 100
120
```

This is the data that has been provided:

```
type Transaction = (Char, Int, Int, String, Int) 
test_log :: [Transaction]    
test_log = [('B', 100, 1104, "VTI", 1),
('B', 200, 36, "ONEQ", 3),
('B', 50, 1223, "VTI", 5),
('S', 150, 1240, "VTI", 9),
('B', 100, 229, "IWRD", 10),
('S', 200, 32, "ONEQ", 11),
('S', 100, 210, "IWRD", 12)]
```

Here is my attempt at the problem:

```
update_money :: Transaction -> Int -> Int
update_money x (action, units, price, stocks, day) = 
    let money_type | action == 'B' = show (units - x)
                | action == 'S' = show (units + x)
                | otherwise     = "Incorrect, please input either B for bought or S for sold. " 
    in
        money_type
```

However, when stating action and (show units) on the same line I am getting a type conversion so am not sure in how I can approach this.

Comment: You might want to start by thinking how your would rewrite the Python to use a `dict` that maps a stock to its profit, rather than separate `profit*` variables.

Comment: Also, `profit += (1 if transaction  == 'B' else -1) * units * price_per_unit`: no `if` statement necessary. The fewer independent statements you have in your Python code, the closer your code gets to being written in a functional style, at which point translation to Haskell becomes trivial.

Comment: Oh, and the type signature you give for `update_money` only processes a *single* transaction, which is already much simpler than the Python equivalent you show (which effectively makes *multiple* calls to a Python version of `update_money` as you describe it).

Comment: The examples you give for `update_money` don't seem to care about the stock symbol and whatever the last element of the transaction is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
update_money (action, units, price, stocks, day) sum = 
    let money_type  | action == 'B' = sum - units * price
                    | action == 'S' = sum + units * price
                    | otherwise     = 0
    in
        money_type

main = print $ update_money ('S', 2, 10, "VTI", 5) 100
```

output in my PC. It works well.

```
Registering library for app2-0.1.0.0..
120
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess the way I'd approach this in Haskell (and in Python, for that matter) would look like this:

```
import qualified Data.Map as M

trans lst = M.fromListWith (+)
    [ (stock, (if transaction == 'B' then id else negate) (units * price_per_unit))
    | (transaction, units, price_per_unit, stock, day) <- lst
    ]
```

Try it in ghci:

```
> trans [('B', 100, 1104, "VTI", 1), ('B', 200, 36, "ONEQ", 3), ('B', 50, 1223, "VTI", 5), ('S', 150, 1240, "VTI", 9), ('B', 100, 229, "IWRD", 10), ('S', 200, 32, "ONEQ", 11), ('S', 100, 210, "IWRD", 12)]
fromList [("IWRD",1900),("ONEQ",800),("VTI",-14450)]
```

Comment: Hi Daniel, how would you do it without importing a function?

Comment: @Stabbathehut If I were not allowed to import `Data.Map`, I would first re-implement `Data.Map`. It is an excellent abstraction boundary. You can peruse its implementation, starting with the most relevant function, [here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.6.6/docs/src/Data.Map.Internal.html#fromListWith).

Comment: Hi Daniel, could you have a look at my edited code on the question please. I am a bit stuck and would appreciate some guidance